# How to load specific layout for resolution on old Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm writing a program for android. I read that the layout-swNdp notation could be used only on SDK 13 level ..But I want the app to adapt to screens 540x960 also on older android versions..like 2.0 2.2
It's possible to do this without using the layout-swNdp folder ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do that programatically, you can get the height and width with the Display object:

```
Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
final int height = display.getHeight();
final int width = display.getWidth();
```

And get the current API level with:

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
```

And then you can use a specific layout for those devices by calling `setContentView()` under an if condition:

```
if ((currentapiVersion <= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) && (height == 960) &&(width == 540)) {
    setContentView(R.layout.your_special_layout);
} else {
    setContentView(R.layout.your_main_layout);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks..Very nice and are you of course?..if I'll use the layout-swNdp folders on tablets even though my target is minimum 1.6 ..the tablet will read the layout-swNdp layout folders or not ?

Comment: My guess is a yes, since it actually depends on the targetSdkVersion.